# Proving this identity using summation by parts

Tags: number-theory, summation, analytic-number-theory

This problem was left as an exercise from the notes which I am self studying and I am not able to get any ideas on how to solve it.

Problem:  Let $$\pi(x;q,a)=\#\{p \leq x : p=a \mod q\}$$ and $$\psi(x; q,a)= \sum_{n\leq x ,  n= a \mod q} \Lambda(n)$$

The prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions states that if $\gcd(a,q)=1$, then as $n\to \infty$ ($q$ fixed),

$$\pi (x;q,a) = \frac{1} {\psi(q)} \text{Li}(x) + O(x e^{-c (\log x)^{1/2}})$$ and $$\psi(x;q,a) = \frac{x} {\psi(q)} +O( x e^{-c (\log x)^{1/2}})$$

Applying Summation by parts, $$\sum_{ p\leq x, p=a \mod q } \frac{\log p}{p} = \frac{1} {\phi(q)} \log x +O(1) $$

> I am not able to deduce that how by applying summation by parts I will get the required result. I thought of using Abel's identity and Euler summation formula but I am  not able to understand how to deal with $p=a (\mod q) $ that is in the summation.

Can you please help me in proving this?

Comment: summation by parts involves general coefficients $a_n$.  maybe that means congruence conditions aren't an issue.

Comment: Just define a characteristic function for that condition and put that in the sequence $a_n$.

Answer (score 1):

It follows from the second identity that

$$
\vartheta(x;q,a)=\sum_{\substack{p\le x\\p\equiv a(q)}}\log p={x\over\varphi(q)}+O(xe^{-c(\log x)^{1/2}}),
$$

allowing us to perform partial summation as follows:

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{\substack{p\le x\\p\equiv a(q)}}{\log p\over p}
&=\int_{2^-}^x{\mathrm d\vartheta(t;q,a)\over t} \\
&={1\over\varphi(q)}\int_2^x{\mathrm dt\over t}+\int_{2^-}^x\frac1t\mathrm d\left\{O(te^{-c(\log t)^{1/2}})\right\} \\
&={\log x\over\varphi(q)}+O(1).
\end{aligned}

Comment: i could be wrong, but i don't think using riemann-stieltjes will help the OP

Comment: Riemann-Stieltjes is just summation by parts in a different notation.

Comment: i agree, but i stick with my comment

Comment: @TravorLZH what symbol is $\vartheta(x;q,a)$? I never used in question and I am sorry but I don't understand it.

Comment: @YOja It's Chebyshev's theta function for arithmetic progressions, which sums $\log p$ over $p\le x$ and $p\equiv a\pmod q$.

Comment: @TravorLZH Can you please tell how did you deduced  that $\vartheta(x;q,a)={x\over\varphi(q)}+O(xe^{-c(\log x)^{1/2}})$ ?

Comment: @YOja plug in the definition of $\Lambda(n)$, and you will see that $\psi(x;q,a)-\vartheta(x;q,a)\le\psi(x)-\vartheta(x)=O(x^{1/2})$

Comment: @TravorLZH If I am not wrong, we will get $\psi (x,q,a)\leq \psi(x) $ and $-\theta(x) \leq \theta(x,q,a)$ and this will not prove that $\psi(x,q,a) -\theta(x,q,a) \leq \psi (x) -\theta(x)$ and I am afraid to say but I am also not able to see how you deduced that $\psi(x) -\theta (x) =O(x^{1/2})$. I checked apostol's book again but there is no result mentioning this. Can you please elaborate on both of these results.

Comment: By definition, there is $\psi(x)-\vartheta(x)=\sum_{2\le k\le\log_2x}\sum_{\substack{p\le x^{1/k}\\p\equiv a(q)}}\log p$. Bounding the remaining part by dropping $p\equiv a(q)$ should give $O(x^{1/2})$.